# Is there traceback in Objective-C, similar to Python?

Tags: python, objective-c

I've been learning to code in objective-c but while waiting for a couple of books I'm reading through an online book which mentions that Python has something called traceback, and it seems awfully helpful in terms of debugging, especially for beginners I'd guess.

Does objective-c have this feature, or anything like it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the stacktrace yes its possible in Objective-C

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

Which is useable from any thread and can be very useful sometimes.